# Check matching records from an array in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, codeigniter

I want to check if there is any record in the database that matches any value in an array in codeigniter. 
I used `result_array()` to fetch values from tableA, now I want to check whether any of the returned values matches any record from tableB. 
Normally, one would use `foreach` to get the values, but I dont think using `foreach` would give the desired results. Because i'd have to do it like this

```
foreach($data as $d){
   $this->db->from('tableB')->where('data', $d)->get()->row();
}
```

This doesn't seem to make so much sense, especially since I can't figure out how to get the returned rows.

Any idea how I could do that?

Comment: Please post your expected return from table and post your table structure so i can help you.

Comment: You shouldn't make connection to DB in foreach loop. Better would be to get all results and then check with `in_array()` ([check example](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php#example-5647)).